# Cross-entropy calculation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, machine-learning

This is a really dumb question, but here goes: is there a way to compute cross-entropy of two probability distributions? There is `CrossEntropyLayer[]`,  so *Mathematica* knows about cross-entropy, but no actual function, it seems, unless I am missing something obvious...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one, but you can always use `Expectation[]`...

Comment: @J.M. So, for symbolic dist, `Expectation[Log[PDF[...], ...]`?

Comment: Like that, yes. The bonus is that `Expectation[]` will automatically handle it depending on whether both distributions are discrete or continuous.

Comment: Also, for the case that this can't be computed symbolically, there's `NExpectation`